# Delete a retain message using aws-iot client on a react-native app

Tags: javascript, react-native, aws-sdk, mqtt, aws-iot

I wanted to delete a retain message from a topic on mqtt. The document suggest to publish an empty string or null to that particular topic with the retain flag as true to delete the retain message.
But as soon as i publish something with the retain flag as true the client disconnects and reconnects again.

```
client.publish(topic, null, {retain: true})
```

i am using npm package aws-iot-device-sdk which has this note.

> Note, AWS IoT doesn't support retained messages; setting retain flag to 'true' for message publishing, including Last Will and Testament messages, will result in connection termination.

i want to delete the particular retain message.

i also tried getting the retained message using the fetch api call but i am getting 403 error.
I might be missing some credentials in the api call.

```
fetch(lwtUrl, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: {
        'accessKey': credentials.accessKeyId,
        'secretKey': credentials.secretAccessKey,
        'aws-region': 'region',
        'service-name': 'mqtt',
        'session-token': credentials.sessionToken,
      },
    },
  }).then(res => {
    console.log('res', res);
  });
```

Also wanted to know if there is a way we can delete it via a fetch request.??

Comment: Given AWS doesn't support retained messages and it's disconnecting you when you try and publish one, what makes you think there is one? Do you actually receive a message with the retained bit set when you subscribe to the topic?

Comment: @hardillb if i try to do anything withe the retain flag on it disconnects. But I wanted to delete a retain message. Any suggestion on how to achieve it?

Comment: The point in trying to make is, the situation you describe should be impossible to get into (it's not possible for there to be a retained message to remove), so why do you think there is one.

Comment: i have a scenario where a device publish to its LWT topic with the retain flag as true. When the device is removed i have to delete that message but i am not able to do it via aws because it refrains us to do it.
I will be trying other mqtt clients for it.

Comment: Changing MQTT client will not help you as the problem is the broker will always try and disconnect if it tries to set the retained flag. It should not be possible for the LWT to set the retained flag either. You have not answered the question of if you actually see the retained message if you subscribe to the topic, so I still don't think there is an actual problem to solve here (because it should not be possible to ever set a retained message)

Comment: Yes I do see the retained message when i subscribe to the topic. i have a sensor which on connect/disconnect publish to that topic and when a device subscribe it gets the data. Now what i want is on removing that sensor i wanted to delete that particular retained message.

Comment: Publishing empty retained message from AWS Console : MQTT Test Client worked for me